# Get selected date from fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I added the calendar to my asp.net mvc 2 application from [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) .

I want to pick the selected date where I am going to enter the event. How can I get selected date?

Also I want to save this date and corresponding event to the database. How to do this also ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this code when you setup the plugin

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
         // start contains the date you have selected
         // end contains the end date. 
         // Caution: the end date is exclusive (new since v2).
         var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
         alert(["Event Start date: " + moment(start).format(),
                "Event End date: " + moment(end).format(),
                "AllDay: " + allDay].join("\n"));
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Please note that I have just included the options needed to answer your question.

For further information refer to the very good made [plugin documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/).

Comment: when i am select 2014 aug 11 - 16 i'm getting like this  Event Start date- 1410134400000  and Event end date-1410652800000, couldn't understand this  first is for year se

Comment: include moment js @SebinSimon

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    }
});
```

Comment: thax but i want get month on calendar load or next prev button click.