# Full Calender not showing selected Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I want to popup selectedDate on Date Select

I used a solution from previous post :

[get selected date from fullcalendar jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959258/get-selected-date-from-fullcalendar-jquery)

this is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/100thgear/h9cc6/

My Code (No Error on Firebug)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
         // start contains the date you have selected
         // end contains the end date. 
         // Caution: the end date is exclusive (new since v2).
         var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
         alert(["Event Start date: " + moment(start).format(),
                "Event End date: " + moment(end).format(),
                "AllDay: " + allDay].join("\n"));
    }
});
});
```

but still it is not working ....Calender appears Fine

What Am I missing .Am I miissng Any External CSS or JQuery link ??

Comment: You need to include momentjs library!

Comment: still not working ---see http://jsfiddle.net/100thgear/h9cc6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F12 for the console is your friend ;)

hasTime is not a function, so changing the one line to this worked:

```
var allDay = !start.hasTime && !end.hasTime;
```

fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5o66w860/

Comment: Yes .thanks a Lot .. I have been searching the solution for days  ,In different Calenders